# Simple modification of Hello World

Tags: c++, windows, console

I'm a beginner C++ programmer. There has to be simple mistake somewhere but I can't figure it out why it won't compile.

Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "GUI.h"
#include "GUI.cpp"

int main()
{
    Display("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

GUI.h

```
#pragma once
void Display(std::string param0);
```

GUI.cpp

```
#include "GUI.h"
void Display(std::string param0)
{
    std::cout << param0;
}
```

Errors are:

```
Namespace "std" has no member "string" and "cout"

'String' is not a member of 'std'

'String' undeclared identifier

syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'param0'

'{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

However, when I paste code directly into Main.cpp creating

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void Display(std::string param0);

void Display(std::string param0)
{
    std::cout << param0;
}

int main()
{
    Display("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine so the problem lies probably with incorrect use of #includes.

I always thought that the include directive just "injects" code into main.cpp and it's just for organizational purposes and for dividing code into smaller pieces but now I'm confused.

How this code should look like and why?

Are there already any bad programming habits in this piece of code?

EDIT: Thanks for help, it finally compiles so I assume it should be done that way:

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "GUI.h"
int main()
{
    Display("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

GUI.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
void Display(std::string param0);
```

can also be done as

```
#ifndef GUI_H
#define GUI_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
void Display(std::string param0);
#endif
```

GUI.cpp

```
#include "GUI.h"
void Display(std::string param0)
{
    std::cout << param0;
}
```

Comment: You are missing #include<string> in your GUI.h

Comment: Don't include source  (.cpp) files.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8wa1G3TpUVC0xEda).

Comment: Also, read your learning material more carefully, including the .cpp like that is nonsense.

Comment: BTW, `#pragma once` is not part of the *standard* language.  You may want to use traditional include guards.

Comment: There is no need to include `<iostream>` in `"gui.h"`. `<iostream>` is a heavy (large) header that should be avoided as a dependency for your own headers. Include it in each .cpp file where it's needed, e.g. in `"gui.cpp"`. Where you need to use related types in a header, include [`<iosfwd>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iosfwd) instead of `<iostream>`. This is more light-weight header that only provides the types and not e.g. operator `<<` or `endl`, and it's the only such "forward" header in the standard library -- precisely because `<iostream>` is so large and costly.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that there exists lighter version, it will be helpful indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgot to add `#include <string>` into `GUI.h`. There is no need to include `GUI.cpp` file.